# I suggest a selectable "reason" for a down/up-vote, and an option for further comment

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

It was suggested that requiring a category for a down-vote would create an asymmetry between up- and down-votes, so I am amending my suggestion to include up-votes along with down-votes.

This may be a partial duplicate, but the two ideas seem to belong together, so I am repeating the "comment" suggestion, (but adding to it the suggestion that an anonymous comment feature be added for down-votes.)

When I invest considerable time and effort in formulating and composing a question which I post to math.se, and have it down-voted, that is discouraging.  It reduces my motivation to contribute, and rarely communicates anything helpful.  I often suspect some kind of bigotry, bias or other petty motive is behind the down-vote, rather than an effort to improve quality of content.

As I understand it, the  reason down-voting is anonymous is that it encourages people to down-vote because, for some reason down-votes are considered valuable.  IMO this encourages quantity over quality of down-votes.

I will suggest that down-votes be categorized.  In other words, down-voting would require the selection of a reason (poorly formulated|off-topic|insufficient effort|is open-ended|don't like user|that's homework you should do on your own).  I also recommend including the suggestion that the down-voter leave a comment (possibly anonymously) explaining the reason.

I understand that anonymity of down-voting is a way of avoiding "down-vote wars", but it has its drawbacks as well.

I believe the suggested features would also encourage participants to be more thoughtful in their voting practices.  That is, it would remind them of what a vote is intended to communicate.

Comment: How do you propose to force people to be honest about their down-vote reasons?

Comment: Variants on this idea have been discussed *many* times before here. Some of the main problems are 1) lack of anonymity leading to harassment, 2) a failure of duality (in the sense that upvotes aren't treated in the same way), 3) a bunch more noise that's not necessarily helpful, especially since people have no reason to explain their votes, and 4) that requiring vote explanations is a fundamental change in how things work here and decreases the usefulness of the feedback, because users can be targeted for making quality-control efforts.

Comment: We really can't protect against dishonesty.  But the value of honest down-votes would be increased.

Comment: How to tell if an  upvote/downvote is honest or dishonest?

Comment: @ArcticChar isn't that already a problem?

Comment: You said the value of honest downvote should be increased. I am asking how to locate such votes.

Comment: @ArcticChar the good-faith assumption is that most votes are honest.  We should be concerned with the quality of honest participation.  We can't protect against dishonesty.  But, even if a vote is not properly motivated, having it categorized would be more constructive than the simple implication that "I don't like the questions (or the person asking it)"

Comment: Why do you propose this for downvotes? What about upvotes? What about "I've upvoted this because it was downvoted, and I don't know what kind of quality this answer has, but I just dislike the fact it has a negative score" reason for upvote? Wouldn't that be great too?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I amended my suggestion to include up-votes.  One of the categories could simply be "I like/dislike the question".  At least that would communicate to the other person what motivated the vote.

Comment: @AsafKaragila There is only one choice: allow voting on voting. Recursively probably.

Comment: @rschwieb: Recursive implies that there is a well-founded relation to define the halting condition. I don't see that here.

Comment: @rschwieb I don't understand how that is the "only" solution; or even an effective solution.  My primary objective is to improve the quality of feedback communicated by votes, by including more information than a simple Boolean value.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton Sure, you can gauge the quality of the votes by their meta-votes. But yeah seriously if you didn't detect it already this was tongue-in-cheek.  I did not think that aspect would go unnoticed.

Answer (score 1):

This pops up if you flag a post:

[image: On first flag]

Something similar to this, pops up if you select should be closed: 
[image: Should be closed image]

Do you see how, a lot of these are similar to the suggestions you make for the downvotes ? You'll Also find that you can get 5 downvotes on an answer, before it cancels the reputation points from a single upvote. On a question the downvotes mean more. You'll also find a downvote asks you to leave a comment, it's not generally enforced. People who are spammy or [crackpots](https://primes.utm.edu/notes/crackpot.html), don't generally give up unless challenged. They are subject to the [Dunning Kruger effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pOLmD_WVY-E&app=desktop), as are some of your own postings.

Past postings by you, state that you being off-topic is on the community. Not entirely true, your being off-topic could come down to the level of postings, in a given math community. More advanced, adequately researched and on topic questions, are likely to warrant moving them to MathOverflow. Off-topic rants, could have been simply deleted, instead of downvoted.

Comment: "They are subject to the Dunning Kruger effect, as are some of your own postings." This sounds borderline like a personal attack. This is not a bad answer, but try to keep your comments restricted to the topic at hand, not the user themselves, please.

Comment: topic included the persons postings in the body of the original post.