# Feature: options for downvoting an answer similar to the options for closing a question

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, down-votes

For the most part, users give very useful comments that help improve the question/answer.

But I am sure many of you too must have come across sometimes the mysterious offshoot downvote and then spend 5-10 minutes trying to figure out what the exact issue was. (Which is actually a good thing sometimes because it improves the overall answer.)

> Suggestion1: I was wondering if it would be a good idea to prompt a user with a small reminder after downvoting eg. "we encourage you to add some feedback to help improve the answer.".

For example, sometimes someone might find the answer to be too heuristic or missing some key details or the question is not actually answering the OP question fully.

One concern here is that it might discourage downvoting because users might not want to get into a debate with the poster of the answer.

> Suggestion2: So another suggestion is to provide a list of options for downvoting an answer similar to the options we choose when closing a question eg. "the answer contains mistakes", "the answer doesn't resolve the original question", "the answer is too heuristic, not enough detail".

I thought this must have been discussed before, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Suggestion 1 is already there, at least for low-rep users. When I downvoted a question or an answer in e.g. Academia.SE, where I have ~500 rep, the reminder "Please consider adding a comment if you think this post can be improved." pops up.

Comment: There are some related older posts - although mostly they suggest this for *both questions and answers*. On this meta: [I suggest a selectable "reason" for a down/up-vote, and an option for further comment](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30351).
On [meta.se]: [Canned reasons for upvote and downvote (with an example of how it would work)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/50030). (This one is marked status-declined. You can have a look [at the linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/50030), too.)

Comment: Or this one: [Select from list of reasons when performing downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144851). Again, there are [several linked questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/144851).)

Comment: If you are not proposing to add this effort to upvotes as well, you are choosing to make curation of posts that don't meet the standards more difficult, when we already have an overwhelming issue of such posts. Please explain why you think curation should require more effort than it already takes, but upvoting doesn't need this same justification.